# VCXO Control Range Above 0V

Tags: vco

So I think this this going to be a simple answer but I just cant really find anythign that confirms this for me.

This is the VCXO in question:
[Q-Tech QTCV356](https://q-tech.com/wp-content/uploads/QPDS-0207-QTCV356.pdf)

The control voltage range is 0.3V min, 3V max.

If this VCXO is controlled by a DAC that outputs 0 to 3V, some resolution is lost since the output of the VCXO will be unchanged through the 0 to 0.3V output range of the DAC.

Assuming this is true and that changing the components is not an option, I would think the simplest solution would be to bias the output of the DAC so that it outputs 0.3V-3V.

Am I thinking about this correctly?

And what is the point of having a control voltage of 0.3 to 3V rather than 0 to 3V?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your interpretation is correct.

The simplest, and possibly most precise, solution is to not bias the DAC but to just ignore the 10% (or 20% counting the top end) of resolution that is lost. DAC resolutions go up in increments of 2:1 so chances are the 10% or 20% is insignificant.

What is the point? Just speculation, it's easier inside the oscillator. Also it's good to avoid the extremes of the power supply rails because it's not always possible to get accurate analog circuitry that operates very close to the rails, so keeping 300mV away from the positive rail and from ground makes sense.

Comment: thanks for the clarification. What do you mean by DAC resolutions go up in increments of 2:1? Do you mean by every one bit you're adding 2^n+1 of resolution?

Comment: and what about being at the rails makes analog circuitry inaccurate?

Comment: 1. Yes. 2. It gets progressively more difficult to get full accuracy, speed and stability the closer  you  get to the rails, depending on the technology and what needs to be driven. For example, a rail-to-rail op-amp may not be able to drive much current or may exhibit small scale instability when the output is close to the rails.

Comment: aren't rail-to-rail op amps special types of op amps that are meant to operate close to the rails? [Rail to Rail Amp] (https://www.analog.com/en/analog-dialogue/raqs/raq-issue-141.html). Based of the link I do now understand why it is best to stay away from the rails due to input offset voltage and other parameters degrading at least for the conventional amp as well as the rail to rail amp (although it seems the noise is much less for the rail to rail amp)